# How to render promise on a initial load of a React Native component

Tags: es6-promise, react-native

I'm trying to use React Native's `DatePickerAndroid`. But I want to show it on an initial load of an component. But the problem is that `DatePickerAndroid` is a `promise` ([see docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerandroid.html)) and I could't load it on initial render.

Thus, what I have is :

```
render(){
    let datePicker = <DatePickerIOS date={this.state.selectedValue} mode="date" timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={this.state.timeZoneOffsetInHours * 60} onDateChange={(date) => { this.setState({selectedValue: date})}} />;
    if (Platform.OS === "android"){
         datePicker = this.showAndroidDatePicker()
    } 

    return(
       <View>          
          {datePicker}
       </View>
    )
}
```

Where `showAndroidDatePicker` function is as in the docs :

```
showAndroidDatePicker = async () => {
    try {
        const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
           date: this.state.selectedValue
        });
        if (action !== DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
           var date = new Date(year, month, day);
           this.setState({selectedValue: date.toLocaleDateString()});
        }
    }catch ({code, message}) {
        console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
    }
};
```

But when I run it on `android` I get big red screen with an error :

> Objects are not valid as a React Child (found: Object with keys ({_45,
>   _81, _64, _54}). ......

Any idea how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You effectively tried to render the result of `open`, which according the docs tells you what the user picked. So you probably don't want to render it or have it anywhere in your render function.

Add a button to open the date picker, and when pressed call the `open` method. The result of it will tell you what the user picked.